# Работа с try catch. Почему не выводится результат работы кода?

Tags: javascript

Задание: Реализовать функцию, в которой есть возможность вести индекс животного, которое вы хотите увидеть. Если пользователь вводит индекс, не содержащий животное, код выдаст ошибку **TypeError**, когда имя ссылается на неопределенное значение.
Вокруг кода есть блок `try`, вызывающий ошибку `TypeError`. Существует блок `catch`, перехватывающий ошибку и содержащий код для информирования пользователя о том, что он ввел неверный индекс.

Проблема: заключается в том что не выводит `console.log('Данного id не существует, введи от 0 до 6');`

Мой код:

```js
function funcOfAnimals (id) {
    if (objectOfAnimals[id]) {
        return console.log(objectOfAnimals[id]);
    }
    else {
        throw TypeError('Не найден id!');
    }
    try {
        funcOfAnimals(22);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Данного id не существует, введи от 0 до 6');
    }
}
funcOfAnimals(22);
```

`

Comment: Вы написали try-catch внутри функции в её конце, а значит до него выполнение никогда не дойдёт, потому что работа функции будет заранее завершена или строкой return, или строкой throw. Зачем вы вообще написали try-catch внутри функции?

Comment: @andreymal по заданию так нужно сделать. В вопросе я прикрепил задание, за которым нужно реализовать код.

Comment: И в целом, обрабатывать ожидаемое поведение блоком try-catch так себе затея(если вы конечно не делаете этого в учебных целях). Обычно try-catch используется там, где что то гипотетически может пойти не так и возникнет ошибка, которую вы не ожидаете и не обрабатываете.

Comment: в задаче не скзаано, что блок try должен быть внутри функции и запускать рекурсию

Comment: Вообще для чего тут использовать trycatch? Где тут непредвиденная ситуация? + throw в не блока try.. + завязывали бы вы с всякими скилбоксами, они вас ничему хорошему не научат)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо вызов функции обернуть блоком **try-catch**

```js
const objectOfAnimals = {
  1: 'Кот'
}

function funcOfAnimals (id) {
  if (objectOfAnimals[id]) {
    return console.log(objectOfAnimals[id]);
  }
  else {
    throw TypeError('Не найден id!');
  }
}

try {
  funcOfAnimals(22);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Данного id не существует, введи от 0 до 6');
}

try {
  funcOfAnimals(1);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Данного id не существует, введи от 0 до 6');
}
```

UPD: При желании, блок try-catch можно встроить и в функцию

```js
const objectOfAnimals = {
  1: 'Кот'
}

function funcOfAnimals (id) {
  try {
    if (objectOfAnimals[id]) {
      return console.log(objectOfAnimals[id]);
    }
    else {
      throw TypeError('Не найден id!');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Ошибка', e);
    console.log('Данного id не существует, введи от 0 до 6');
  }
}

funcOfAnimals(22);
funcOfAnimals(1);
```

Comment: я просто полагал что нужно все функцию обернуть в try catch. Спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: @NANO_996 Можно данный блок и в фукнцию встроить. Обновил ответ, добавил пример

Comment: подскажите, я воспользовался вашим кодом где try catch встроен в функцию и мне в консоль выводит только 'Данного id не существует, введи от 0 до 6'. Ошибку в консоль не выдает, почему так ?

Comment: @NANO_996 Потому что вы ее нигде не выводите. Обновил ответ, добавил вывод ошибки в консоль